# String literal in Webpack dynamic import

Tags: webpack, babeljs, dynamic-import

I'm using dynamic imports to create chunks of all locales in a project. The chunks are created, but the client reports this error at runtime:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: locale is not defined
  at _callee$ (main.js?f161:72)
  at tryCatch (runtime.js?98b8:62)
  at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?98b8:288)
  at Generator.prototype.(:8082/d2/v2/search/anonymous function) [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
  at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?c973:3)
  at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?c973:25)
```

The code in question:

```js
// main.js
import { locale } from './config';

(async () => {
  const formatter = new Formatter({ locale });
  const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale,
    formatter,
  });

  // Prints "en-GB", for example, so it's *not* undefined
  console.log(locale);

  const messages = await import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */
    `./locales/${locale}/translations.js`, // <= Error
  );
  i18n.setLocaleMessage(locale, messages);

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    i18n,
    render: h => h(App),
  });
})();
```

Babel configuration:

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
},
```

Locale is exported like so:

```js
// config.js
export const locale = process.env.LOCALE; // e.g. "en-GB"
```

Changing the import path to something static, like `./locales/en-GB/translations.js`, works.

### Edit

This started working when I reassigned `locale` to an intermediate variable, like below:

```js
(async () => {
  // ...

  const tempLocale = locale;

  // Passing `locale` here won't work, but `tempLocale` does...
  const messages = await import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */
    `./locales/${tempLocale}/translations.js`,
  );

  // `locale` is accepted just fine here, for some reason
  i18n.setLocaleMessage(locale, messages);

  // ...
})();
```

I also noticed that when inspecting the `locale` variable in the debugger that *outside* of the IIFE it resolves to the actual string ("en-GB"), but *inside* it resolves to the module in which the `locale` variable is contained. Very confusing, and this solution feels too hacky to be acceptable.

Comment: @AluanHaddad the error message specifically states that `locale` is not defined

Comment: My personal guess would be that the dynamic import feature doesn't support computed expressions for imports (which makes sense when you think about it, what to split?)

Comment: Yes I believe that _is_ the reason but `./locals/${undefined}/translations.js` yields `"./locals/undefined/translations.js"`, not an erorr

Comment: @AluanHaddad Perhaps my second comment is misleading. It doesn't **literally**  say that `locale` is `undefined`, but throws an error nonetheless.

Comment: What error exactly? Edit and add it. Await can be used only inside async function. I've just tested your situation and for me it worked well. Check your Babel config and polyfills.

Comment: @ARS81 Added more details.

Comment: @jlowgren Could you try assigning `./locales/${locale}/translations.js` this to a variable and then using the variable within the import.

Comment: @Royson Fails. Probably due to [this](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-): 

*Fully dynamic statements, such as import(foo), will fail because webpack requires at least some file location information. This is because foo could potentially be any path to any file in your system or project. The import() must contain at least some information about where the module is located, so bundling can be limited to a specific directory or set of files.*

Comment: Weird... It should just wok, and for me it does in latest Chrome with latest version of Webpack and Babel. Is this code running in the browser or is it some kind of mobile app? Have you tried it in the old way like `'./locale/'.concat(locale, '/translations.js')` For me this works either. Have you tried to debug the app? Add a brakepoint to that `console.log` line before the `await import` and watch the value of this `locale` var... Also you could try the import() method [described here](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-) instead the `await import`.

Comment: @jlowgren I saw this example for multiple possible targets [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/?_sm_au_=iVV5sB77rhtRSQfQ#import-). Could you try using `webpackInclude` as illustrated in the example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately they didn't change anything. However I did some more digging and updated the question with more details.

Comment: Same here, @jdlm do you have anything can share? Thanks.

Comment: @floydwch No, unfortunately not. I've since moved on to other projects, and haven't encountered this particular problem again.